# Embed Google+ domain API in google site

Tags: google-plus, google-gadget

I am new in Google+ API and glad that Google finally released Google+ domain API. I have read the documentation and follow through the 'get started' but stumbled on the quick start app that can only use Java and Python. I was expecting that I would be able to embed the Google+ domain API in the company's google site as an app or gadget or widget.

Has anyone had similar problem or find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of the Google+ Domains API is that it is a RESTful API, which means that you can issue calls to it through `GET` and `POST` web requests. The Java and Python libraries make it easier to do by wrapping this functionality into methods that you can call. Whether you wish to use a client library or simply form the API calls yourself, you can build a widget or an app for your site using the specifications for each method found in the [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/).